# Correct method to access a structure pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct AdjMatrix
{
  int nodes;
  int **adjMat;
} graph;

typedef struct Edge
{
  int from,to,weight;
}Edge;


int main(){
  ...

  graph *g=(graph *)malloc(sizeof(graph));
  g-> adjMat = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * vertices);
  for( i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
    g->adjMat[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * vertices);
  }
 ...

 Edge *E = (Edge *)malloc(sizeof(Edge) * maxEdges);

 int nEdges = 0;
 for(i = 0; i < g->nodes ; i++){
    for(j= 0; j< g->nodes; j++){
            if(i <= j){
                    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t\n",i,j,g->adjMat[i][j]);
                    E[nEdges].from = i;
                    E[nEdges].to = j;
                    E[nEdges].weight = g->adjMat[i][j];
                    nEdges++;
            }
            else
                    break;
    }
 }


}
```

As you can see I am accessing the elements of graph g by "->" and elements of Edge E by ".". I am not understanding why the compiler is throwing an error if I access the elements of graph g by "." or elements of Edge E by "->"? Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `E` as an array, and the separate members inside that array are not pointers, so you have to use the dot-operator to access elements.

On the other hand you have `g` which is a pointer to a single `graph` structure, and as a pointer you use the `->` operator.

However, you could access the array `E` as pointers, and the variable `g` as an array. For example, the following two statements are both exactly the same:

```
E[0].from = i;

(E + 0)->from = i;
```

And you can access `g` as an array like this:

```
g[0].nodes = x;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for the explanation. I am now totally clear as to what was happening :)

Answer (score 1):

`g` is declared as being of type `graph*`, making it a pointer-to-graph. This means you must access elements of `g` using the pointer dereference operator: `->`.

`E` is also a pointer, in this case `Edge*` or pointer-to-Edge, but you are using array semantics with it. `E[nEdges]` is *not* a pointer, which means you have to use the `.` operator.

Basically, when you use array semantics you lose the pointer-ness of the variable.

`E` is of type `Edge*`, `E[x]` is of type `Edge`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, both g and e are pointers to structures. An array behaves the same way as a pointer, so e[nEdges] is actually equal to the Edge located at position (e + 12 * nEdges). e[0].from would be the same as e->from.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` operator is used on a pointer to dereference the pointer and then apply the `.` operator. So, for example, `a->b` is the equivalent of `(*a).b`.

The `.` operator accesses a member variable as you said. You have noticed that both `g` and `E` are pointers, but the reason that the `->` operator doesn't work on `E` is because when you are already using the `[]` operator on `E`, which also acts as a dereferencer. For example, the line `E[nEdges].to` is equivalent to `(*(E + nEdges)).to` whereas if you tried to use the `->` operator in this instance it would be equivalent to `(*(*(E + nEdges))).to` which would be one dereference too many.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for the explanation. I am now totally clear as to what was happening :)